# How to define output resolution in Flutter camera plugin?

Tags: flutter, camera

I need to define output resolution from the flutter Camera plugin
By default this plugin generates high level image with several Mb (6MB for an iPhoneX image).
I need a compressed version of the image or a lower resolution.

If it is not managed "natively" by this plugin, other plugin to manage resolution and compression are to slow

Answer (score 1):

The `CameraController` lets you define a Resolution like that:

```
_controller = CameraController(
  camera,
  ResolutionPreset.medium
);
```